# Can we use testcases related to sikuli for selenium grid execution?

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid, sikuli

I have integrated Sikuli with Selenium web driver and it works fine when executed in my local machine. Now I want to execute same scripts using Selenium Grid. Some of my scripts are sikuli related and this testcases are getting failed in grid

Answer (score 0):

You need UI in order to execute Sikuli tests, because they a real UI tests.
In most cases Selenium tests are not a real UI tests and will work headless